# sudo apt-get update error, connection failed

Tags: raspbian, apt, update

When i try to update my rpi i get error like this:

```
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en_GB
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_GB
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en_GB
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release.gpg
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en_GB
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/ui/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/ui/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/ui/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed [IP: 10.0.0.1 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Do you have an active network connection? Can you post the output of `ifconfig` when the above error happens?

Comment: 100% i have connection couse im connected to rpi from other place with ssh :(

Comment: Connection, yes. But do you have an internet connection on the RPi?

Comment: Hmmm, if i wont have connection to the internet is this possible to connect to rpi from another place with diffrent network? im confused right now.

Comment: btw `wget` works so? Do i have internet connection ? also my apache server works from `another` network. Everything works except update

Comment: what happens when you ping 8.8.8.8 and what happens when you ping google.com?

Comment: `50 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 49007ms`

Comment: and minute ago update works, now still error ... I have connection to internet. And why i get allways this ip 10.0.0.1
`ping google.com
PING google.com (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1002ms`

Comment: Seems to me that your rpi or router doesn't handle DNS correct...

Comment: @Gotschi do you know how to solve this ?

Comment: what does your /etc/network/interfaces contain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your log suggests that rasbpian server names (like `mirrordirector.raspbian.org`) are resolved to the IP address `10.0.0.1`, which is [private IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces). At the very least you don't seem to have a working DNS server, but it's entirely possible you have unrelated network problems which prevent the RPi from reaching it.

Try using google DNS `8.8.8.8` instead of whatever is configured now (put `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf`). If that doesn't help, your network connection doesn't work properly and you'll need to fix it.

Comment: Is it possible that some one attacking my network? I didnt make any changes and this happen

Comment: Yes, [DNS spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing) is quite a widespread form of attack. It's hard to say anything for sure with the little info your log provides.

Comment: This was DNS isue, i config on router DNS to Google and now every thing is OK thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you have followed Dmitry's advice regarding DNS, if you still have an issue...

Check your etc/hosts file to see if you have domains pointed at 10.0.0.1. Unlikely but worth looking.
or
Ping google.com to see if you are getting out there